# How to install driver tl-wn722n v3 at ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wireless

```
root@root:~# airmon-ng

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
phy1    wlan1       ??????       

root@root:~# 

root@root:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0b05:1788 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. BT-270 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b071 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.0M UVC Webcam / CNF7129
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:010c  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
root@root:~#
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: It is the same for V3